# Is there an R (or Python) package/function to create a backwards selection process on different dependent variables?

Tags: r, regression, feature-selection

I know the title was a little bit overloaded. My question is as follows.

Example dataframe:

```
y1 | y2 | y3 __________ x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | ... | x20
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. data .... .. .. .. .. .. .. 
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. data .... .. .. .. .. .. .. 
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. data .... .. .. .. .. .. .. 
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. data .... .. .. .. .. .. ..
```

There are multiple dependent variables, and the same independent variables for each. I want to know if there is possibly a way to run a backwards selection process on the three (or however many) dependent variables, keeping the same features for each step.

For example,

```
Model 1: 
y1 ~ x1 + ..... + x20 - x3
y2 ~ x1 + ..... + x20 - x3
y2 ~ x1 + ..... + x20 - x3

Model 2:

y1 ~ x1 + ..... + x20 - x3 - x7
y2 ~ x1 + ..... + x20 - x3 - x7
y2 ~ x1 + ..... + x20 - x3 - x7
```

and so on, based off a metric like AIC or adj r^2

If there is no package to do this, I will probably write something from scratch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `caret` package combined with the `leaps` package. This will get you what you want. Here is a simple example. Observe that we use `leapBackward` as a method:

```
library(caret)
library(leaps)

set.seed(123)

train_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

step_model <- train(mpg ~., data = mtcars,
                    method = "leapBackward", 
                    tuneGrid = data.frame(nvmax = 1:4),
                    trControl = train_control)
step_model$results
summary(step_model$finalModel)
```

`nvmax` is the number of variables that can be used for search. Inspect `summary(step_model$finalModel)`. An asterisk tells you that the variable is included in the model. There are good discussions on the subject [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214682/stepwise-regression-in-r-how-does-it-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795953/caret-leap-forward-for-linear-regression-feature-selection-change-nvmax).

Comment: @EricHuang Is this helpful in any way?

Comment: It was, thank you. However to get my result, I ended up modifying the step function

Answer (score 0):

For variable selection you might be better off with a penalized regression model. This can be done with a single model for multiple dependent variables using the [`glmnet` package](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/482594_1ad8bd60595d4f9a8f65c3a57a8ce96a.html). The `cv.glmet` function finds the penalty that maximizes the cross-validated performance. You can run this function directly, or through the `caret` interface. You can also use the [`tidymodels` interface](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/linear_reg.html), which will eventually replace `caret`.